# What's the right way to use toBlocking() in Couchbase Java SDK?

Tags: java, couchbase, rx-java, reactive-programming

Couchbase rookie here, using Couchbase Server v4.0.0 and Java SDK v2.2.3. I have the following code for running a query

```
Observable
            .defer(new Func0<Observable<AsyncN1qlQueryResult>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<AsyncN1qlQueryResult> call() {
                    return bucket.async().query(query);
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<AsyncN1qlQueryResult, Observable<AsyncN1qlQueryRow>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<AsyncN1qlQueryRow> call(AsyncN1qlQueryResult result) {
                    return result.rows();
                }
            })
            .map(new Func1<AsyncN1qlQueryRow, JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public JsonObject call(AsyncN1qlQueryRow row) {
                    return row.value();
                }
            })
            .toList()
            .toBlocking()
            .firstOrDefault(null);
```

The `query` is expected to return two results and I can guarantee there's nothing wrong with it. However, if I let it run, this expression evaluates to null. I suspect there might be something wrong with the way I'm switching to blocking observables or maybe with the deferring.

An interesting observation is that if I run it in debug mode and set a breakpoint at line `return bucket.async().query(query);` and step over it each time using the debugger, I always get a list with 2 elements. (Just another proof that the query is not the culprit.)

Can someone spot anything wrong with my idiom?

Comment: Could you use `doOnNext` to print the result of each step?

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with the code, except that with 2.2.x you don't really need the initial defer.

Comment: What do you get if you remove the `firstOrDefault` and return a list? Is your list empty? Also have a look inside the `AsyncN1qlQueryResult` object - you can `flatMap` in the `N1qlMetrics` object and get access to data about your result.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know your N1QL, check following:

1. You should not start with `Observable.defer()`; just start with `asyncBucket.query()`, since `asyncBucket.query(q)` or `syncBucket.async().query(q)` already implemented with deferred way.
2. `singleOrDefault()` is relevant when used with `toList()`. (But, probably it does not matter in this case.)